# Looping command line program

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python, java

I have many files that I want to process with a software that run via command line. Every execution will take around 8 hours, so I want to automate this process.

How can I make a script that automate this? I imagine the algorithm is like: call the command to process file 1, wait until it finish, call the command to process file 2, etc. It is like a queue. I can write in shell script, python, or java.

Comment: run it on every file in a directory?

Comment: Yes. I will put the file inside a directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using bash by default one command doesn't start until the first one finishes so you can use:

```
/path/to/command /path/to/file1
/path/to/command /path/to/file2
/path/to/command /path/to/file3
```

Put the commands in a script called for example `~/run-all-commands`. Then mark it as executable using:

```
chmod +x ~/run-all-commands
```

Then call the bash script with batch of commands using:

```
~/run-all-commands
```

Answer (score 0):

make `ls` to get a list of your folders.

write a script and call it `script arguments` with the arguments being your folders.

the script does this:

```
sp = $(pwd)

for i in $@
do
  cd $i
  cp ../command .
  ./command
  cd $sp
done
```

I'm assuming `command` is a local script itself. If its something in `~/bin` or `/bin` you can just call it like any other.

Comment: First of all,   you don't need to call `cd $sp` every single time. Just `cd` at the beginning of the script. Second,  it makes no sense to provide  directories as arguments,too, since you can `cd` into folder once.